# Import data from Excel workbook to sqlite3 database in Node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx, node-sqlite3

There is an structured excel workbook, on every sheet has uniq name, on every sheet in the first row contains uniq column names, and the rest of rows contains the values.

There is a solution, export every worksheet to csv file, and use sqlite3 **.import** method on them, (see below) it is slow, and needs too much effort.

```
.mode csv
.separator ";"
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
drop table if exists log;
.import "log.csv" log
COMIT;
```

We want to import data from excel to sqlite3 database, where every worksheet will be a table and the row number of worksheet is the id of the recordset. Due to the first row contains the column names, the **id = row number - 1** The solution:

```
'use strict';
var   XLSX = require('xlsx');
const sql3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var workbook = XLSX.readFile( 'D:\\excel.xlsx' );
var       db = new sql3.Database( 'D:\\database.db' );

var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames; // tables
//console.log( sheet_name_list );
db.serialize( function () {
  db.run( "BEGIN TRANSACTION");
  for( var sheet of workbook.SheetNames ){
    console.log( "Sheet: " + sheet );
    var cells = workbook.Sheets[ sheet ];
    cells['range'] = { R: (cells['!ref']).replace(/[^0-9\:]/g, '' ).split( ':' ),
                       C: (cells['!ref']).replace(/[^A-Z\:]/g, '' ).split( ':' )
                      };
    //console.log( cells );
    var sql = { def: {
                      dro : "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$table$`;",
                      cre : "CREATE TABLE `$table$` ( `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT$cres$ );",
                      ins : "INSERT INTO `$table$` ( $columns$ ) VALUES ( $values$ );"
                     },
                cmd: {
                      dro : {},
                      cre : {},
                      ins : {},
                     },
                cols: {},    
                cres: {},    
                vals: {}    
              };
    
    sql.cols[ sheet ] = "";
    sql.cres[ sheet ] = "";
    sql.vals[ sheet ] = [];
    var rowindex = 0;   
    for(var row=cells.range.R[0];row<=cells.range.R[1];row++){
      sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex ] = [];
      for(var colindex=XLSX.utils.decode_col( cells.range.C[0] );colindex<=XLSX.utils.decode_col( cells.range.C[1] );colindex++){
        var col  = XLSX.utils.encode_col( colindex );
        var cell = cells[ col + "" + row ].v;
        
        if( row == 1 ) {
        //create table
          sql.cols[ sheet ] += " ,`" + cell + "`";
          sql.cres[ sheet ] += ", `" + cell + "` " + 
                              ( cell * 1.0 == cell ?  ( ( cell * 1 + "" )  == cell ? "INTEGER" : "REAL" ) : "TEXT" );
        } else {
          sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex ].push( cell );
          //console.log(sql.vals[ sheet ]);
        }
      }
      if( row==1 ) {
        // drop table
        sql.cmd.dro[ sheet ] = sql.def.dro
                               .replace( "$table$", sheet );
        db.run( sql.cmd.dro[ sheet ] );
        
        // create table
        sql.cmd.cre[ sheet ] = sql.def.cre
                               .replace( "$table$", sheet ) 
                               .replace( "$cres$", sql.cres[ sheet ] );
        db.run( sql.cmd.cre[ sheet ] );
        
        console.log( "Columns: `id`"+ sql.cres[ sheet ] );
        //prepare insert
        sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ] = sql.def.ins
                               .replace( "$table$", sheet ) 
                               .replace( "$columns$", sql.cols[ sheet ].substr( 2 ) )
                               .replace( "$values$",  sql.cols[ sheet ].substr( 2 )
                                                      .replace( /(`[^`]+?`)/g, "?" )
                                        );
        sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ] = db.prepare( sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ] );
      } else {
        //insert prepared values
        console.log( "Row: " + row, "Values: ", sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex ] );
        sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ].run( sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex++ ] );
      }
    }
    //console.log(sql);
    
    sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ].finalize();
  }
  db.run("COMMIT");
});
```

It works fine for me, but with big data it is slow a bit. I have read about better-sqlite3. With that package, would be this procedure faster?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have adopted **better-sqlite** into the process. The difference is huge, this finishes with the transformation in few seconds, instead of minutes.

```
'use strict';
var   XLSX = require('xlsx');
const sql3 = require('better-sqlite3');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile( './perform.xlsx' );
var       db = new sql3( './perform.db' );

var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames; // tables
  
  for( var sheet of workbook.SheetNames ){
    console.log( "Sheet: " + sheet );
    var cells = workbook.Sheets[ sheet ];
    cells['range'] = { R: (cells['!ref']).replace(/[^0-9\:]/g, '' ).split( ':' ),
                       C: (cells['!ref']).replace(/[^A-Z\:]/g, '' ).split( ':' )
                      };
    //console.log( cells );
    var sql = { def: {
                      dro : "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$table$`;",
                      cre : "CREATE TABLE `$table$` ( `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT$cres$ );",
                      ins : "INSERT INTO `$table$` ( $columns$ ) VALUES ( $values$ );"
                     },
                cmd: {
                      dro : {},
                      cre : {},
                      ins : {},
                     },
                cols: {},    
                cres: {},    
                vals: {}    
              };
    
    sql.cols[ sheet ] = "";
    sql.cres[ sheet ] = "";
    sql.vals[ sheet ] = [];
    var rowindex = 0;   
    for(var row=cells.range.R[0];row<=cells.range.R[1];row++){
      sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex ] = [];
      for(var colindex=XLSX.utils.decode_col( cells.range.C[0] );colindex<=XLSX.utils.decode_col( cells.range.C[1] );colindex++){
        var col  = XLSX.utils.encode_col( colindex );
        var cell = ( typeof cells[ col + "" + row ] != "undefined") ? cells[ col + "" + row ].v : "";
        
        if( row == 1 ) {
        //create table
          sql.cols[ sheet ] += " ,`" + cell + "`";
          sql.cres[ sheet ] += ", `" + cell + "` " + 
                              ( cell * 1.0 == cell ?  ( ( cell * 1 + "" )  == cell ? "INTEGER" : "REAL" ) : "TEXT" );
        } else {
          sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex ].push( cell + "");
          //console.log(sql.vals[ sheet ]);
        }
      }
      if( row==1 ) {
        // drop table
        sql.cmd.dro[ sheet ] = sql.def.dro
                               .replace( "$table$", sheet );
        db.exec( sql.cmd.dro[ sheet ] );
        
        // create table
        sql.cmd.cre[ sheet ] = sql.def.cre
                               .replace( "$table$", sheet ) 
                               .replace( "$cres$", sql.cres[ sheet ] );
        db.exec( sql.cmd.cre[ sheet ] );
        
        console.log( "Columns: `id`"+ sql.cres[ sheet ] );
        //prepare insert
        sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ] = sql.def.ins
                               .replace( "$table$", sheet ) 
                               .replace( "$columns$", sql.cols[ sheet ].substr( 2 ) )
                               .replace( "$values$",  sql.cols[ sheet ].substr( 2 )
                                                      .replace( /(`[^`]+?`)/g, "?" )
                                        );
        sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ] = db.prepare( sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ] );
      } else {
        //insert prepared values
        console.log( "Row: " + row, "Values: ", sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex ] );
        sql.cmd.ins[ sheet ].run( sql.vals[ sheet ][ rowindex++ ] );
      }
    }
  }
db.close();
```